# Tableau Mapping, BEA Codes?

Tags: mapping, gis, tableau-api, fips, bea

Tableau supports FIPS codes for US Geography. Does anyone know if it also supports BEA County Codes? I cannot seem to find an answer online.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is as good of proof and any that Tableau is using Census counties rather than BEA.

The example [HERE](https://www.economy.com/support/blog/buffet.aspx?did=06CB7A74-862E-4F72-A155-70D54B3597B2) makes mention of the two counties: Albemarle County and Charlottesville City being represented as one in the BEA codes.

When we plot those counties in Tableau we see that they are in fact two separate counties.

[image]

If you would like to use the BEA county designations you can either manipulate the data prior to bringing it into Tableau or in Tableau using Groups.

Create a group

[image]

Add the counties to the group

[image]

Now we just have one single county

[image]

Hope this helps. Happy vizzing!